# How can i prevent some values from being updated if i am passing an object to the model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinder

I have an object named Visit with the following properties:-

Note
DoctorID
VisitTypeID
CreatedBy
Date
VisitID
PatientID
StatusID
Timestamp

In the Edit view the user can only edit the following two properties :-
Note
DoctorID
So i have added the other properties as hidden field in my edit view as follow:-

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Visit</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorID)
            </div>

            <p>
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VisitTypeID)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VisitID)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatientID)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StatusID)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

I haveto include all the properties in my edit view since i am passing a Visit object to my post edit action method,, which looks as follow:-

```
  [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(Visit visit)
            {
                if (!(visit.Editable(User.Identity.Name)))
                {
                    return View("NotFound");
                }
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        repository.UpdateVisit(visit);
                        repository.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
    var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                    var clientValues = (Visit)entry.Entity;

                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                    + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "

    //code goes here
```

So i am worried about the above approach for these reasons:-
1. an attacker might modify the hiddenfields values.
2. i can not define a [Bind(Include = "....")] at my Visit model class.

**So i am unable to decide if i should continue using this approach OR there is a better approach to follow**

Comment: but if i use a ViewModle then how i can keep track of the timestamp value,, since the ViewModel will not have related timestamp values in the database.. As in my action method i am checking for the DbUpdateConcurrencyException which will be raised if no timestamp value was found during the edit process...

Comment: You can put the timestamp in the ViewModel

Comment: thanks for the reply; is there an example of how i can use viewModels instead of using the Model objects for the CRUD operations...

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially re-pull the `Visit` object in your controller then carry over only the two fields you wish to populate. That would secure that only those two fields are edited.

```
Visit existingVisit = /* retrieve Visit */;
existingVisit.Note = visit.Note;
existingVisit.DoctorID = visit.DoctorID;
repostistory.Update(existingVisit);
reposistory.SaveChanges();
```

However, I may event take it a step further and create a view model for that specific action which would only include the fields you're concerned with.

Comment: if i use your apprach to search for the visit object and re-pull it with the values ,, then the DbUpdateConcurrencyException will never be raised ,, so i need to pass an object to the action method to be able to raise the DbUpdateConcurrencyException when required...

Comment: You don't use timestamp based duplication checks? Any time we've ever had multi-user changes we've used a "lastupdated" column that is re-checked at save to se if it concurs with the object we're trying to save (then of course updated after the update's pushed).

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by "You don't use timestamp based duplication checks",, but timestamp will be included in the where clause for the Edit process and incase the edit process did not update any object the DbUpdateConcurrencyException will be raised ,, which means that the object was modified by another user after retrivinf the object...